# symbols "#@+" in PHP comments

Tags: php, special-characters, phpdoc, docblocks

I have found some special symbols "#@+" and "#@-" in the comments/documentation in ZF1. Example:

```
/**#@+
 * @access protected
 */
```

(https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Mail.php#L54)

I have seen before in another different repositories.

What do these mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are PHP DocBlock templates declarations. There should be an ending tag `/**#@-*/` in the file as well. It allows you to specify the same documentation across multiple properties, methods or constants.

A better explaination with examples can be found here:
http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/how-to-use-docblock-templates-in-phpdoc

Comment: It is interesting that this info is found on the site you mention, on Wikipedia, but not on the official [site](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html). Or did I miss it?

Comment: It's pretty ironic that they have yet to document it ;)

Comment: I do not believe that phpDocumenter v2 supports this syntax.  It was only supported in 1.x, and I'm not sure if there are plans to add it in 2.x.